# Sync local files to S3 similar to Robocopy

Tags: sync, windows-server-2008, robocopy, amazon-s3

I am looking for a way to synchronize an entire local folder structure to Amazon S3, similar to how one might synchronize two folders using Robocopy.

Whatever solution I come up with needs to be scheduled to run periodically from the Windows Task Scheduler.  So anything that requires a GUI to perform the synchronization is not a viable solution.

[Standalone Windows .EXE command line utility for Amazon S3 & EC2](http://s3.codeplex.com/) looked promising, but seems to have been abandoned and would not work when I tried to use it.  Possibly a difference in the way that security is handled now compared to that software's most recent release.

Answer (score 2):

According to this post you should be able to access the files via WebDav.

[Accessing Amazon S3 via WebDav](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=249270)

Therefore, in theory, the Server / Computer which you would like to upload files from could have a Batch File setup on it to map the WebDav folder to a drive letter on that machine and then execute a robocopy command from the local drive and folder to the newly mapped drive and folder.  This batch file then may be attached to the Windows Task Scheduler at the desired intervals.